# How do I get the context menu Resharper Debug and Run Tests options In Visual Studio 2019 (at test class/method level)

Tags: context-menu, visual-studio-2019, resharper

**VS Pro** 2019 Version 16.11.5

**Resharper Ultimate** 2020.1.4

In VS2017, with an earlier version of Resharper, I would see two sets of context menu options for debugging/running tests when I right click on a test class or test method.  One Run/Debug set was to run the test(s) using VS test explorer.  The other set was to Run/Debug the test(s) using Resharper test sessions.

In the new version I see VS's options, but not Resharper's.

This screenshot if from a different computer, but shows the context menu options I saw previously in VS2017.

[image]

The top "Run Test(s)" and "Debug Test(s)" options are from VS.

The bottom "Run Unit Tests" and "Debug Unit Tests" options come from R#.

How do I get the missing context menu Resharper Debug and Run options to show up when I right click on a test class or test method?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot by chance of what you are expecting?

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is the 'intended' solution, but 2 uninstalls and reinstalls solved the issue.  It may have been an install corruption, or some hidden configuration setting I never found.